# How to set the padding of a single BorderPane region in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, padding, borderpane

I have created a borderpane with javafx and use two regions: center and top. I'd like to set padding to the top region only.

`myBorderPane.setPadding(Insets value)` won't do, because this also sets the padding for the center region. I want to set it for the top region ONLY. Is there a way to do this?

I know I could just add another pane like a VBox to the top region and set the padding for that. Just wondering if there is a way to give the region a padding without having to add this VBox.

Comment: What node did you use for `setTop()`? Add the padding to that node.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the `static void setMargin(Node child, Insets value)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html#setMargin-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.geometry.Insets-) to do this:

```
BorderPane borderPane = ...
Node top = ...
Insets topInsets = ...
borderPane.setTop(top);

BorderPane.setMargin(top, topInsets);
```